# Printing a return value of a function without using return statement

Tags: c

I am trying this following C program.

```
add (int a , int b)
    {    // Do nothing   
    }

void main()
   {
       printf("%x\n", add(1,1));
       printf("%x\n", add(1,1));
   }
```

GCC gives me output as below: 
Output: 1 
        2

Can someone explain why these values are getting printed. Even though I assume it is garbage, sequence of 1 and 2 is confusing for me.

Comment: do you get the same output every time?

Comment: Yes. I executed it multiple times and the same output.

Comment: BTW, enable all warnings and debug info in your compiler (i.e. `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`). Then use the debugger(`gdb`)

Answer (score 10):

This is undefined behaviour. Try to run your program with different compiler, you will get different value.

Try with a functions which uses different stack variables on the basis of some input. You will get different value as variable stack will change.

Comment: I just ran some tests on ideone.com and there I got 0 as output each time... so UB confirmed

Comment: This is because compiler has generated code in some manner that you are getting 0. But it is not guaranteed that 0 will always be generated. Try to run more function on the basis of some user input. You might get different output.

Comment: I agree. But could you kindly tell me what do these values correspond to? Is the function returning garbage values without using return statement?

Comment: As per my knowledge, it pops the value from stack or register (it depends on the compiler) and which could be anything. And this value is not guaranteed and may result in some garbage value.

Comment: It *is* garbage. The values are random, in the sense that *you cannot predict what will be returned*. This is a Not A Question because there is no 'correct' answer possible; and is not because the C standard does not describe what should happen under circumstances **beyond proper use** of the language.

Answer (score 0):

Compiler dependent behaviour. **DO NOT IGNORE COMPILER WARNINGS**